# MoveToEx and LineTo doesnt draw using MAKEPOINTS stored in vertices(push_back) win32 c++

Tags: c++, winapi, drawing

unless I set, for example, LineTo(hdc,50,50) it will draw from point(50,50) but no matter what I do I can't make it work using MAKEPOINTS and store it in Vertex class(class is correct)

please help

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            POINTS clickPoint = MAKEPOINTS(lParam); 
            connectLines.push_back(Vertex(clickPoint.x, clickPoint.y));                 
            MoveToEx(hdc, clickPoint.x, clickPoint.y, NULL);            
            LineTo(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        }
        break;
```

edit: I'm adding WM_PAINT and Vertex class and Vertex header

```
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;         
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...

            for (Vertex points : connectLines) {
                HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 7, RGB(255, 0, 0));
                HGDIOBJ oldPen = SelectObject(hdc, pen);
                SelectObject(hdc, oldPen);
                DeleteObject(pen);
            }
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
```

Vertex header

```
#pragma once
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex();
    Vertex(int x, int y);
    Vertex(const Vertex& other);

    // Accessors
    int GetX() const;
    void SetX(const int x);
    int GetY() const;
    void SetY(const int y);

    // Assigment operator
    Vertex& operator= (const Vertex& rhs);

    bool operator== (const Vertex& rhs) const;

    const Vertex operator+ (const Vertex& rhs) const;

private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};
```

Vertex header

```
#include "Vertex.h"

Vertex::Vertex()
{
    _x = 0.0f;
    _y = 0.0f;
}

Vertex::Vertex(int x, int y)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}

Vertex::Vertex(const Vertex& other)
{
    _x = other.GetX();
    _y = other.GetY();
}

int Vertex::GetX() const
{
    return _x;
}

void Vertex::SetX(const int x)
{
    _x = x;
}

int Vertex::GetY() const
{
    return _y;
}

void Vertex::SetY(const int y)
{
    _y = y;
}

Vertex& Vertex::operator=(const Vertex& rhs)
{
    // Only do the assignment if we are not assigning
    // to ourselves
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        _x = rhs.GetX();
        _x = rhs.GetY();
    }
    return *this;
}

// The const at the end of the declaration for '==' indicates that this operation does not change
// any of the member variables in this class

bool Vertex::operator==(const Vertex& rhs) const
{
    return (_x == rhs.GetX() && _y == rhs.GetY());
}

// You can see three different uses of 'const' here:
//
// The first const indicates that the method changes the return value, but it is not moved in memory
// The second const indicates that the parameter is passed by reference, but it is not modified
// The third const indicates that the operator does not change any of the memory variables in the class

const Vertex Vertex::operator+(const Vertex& rhs) const
{
    return Vertex(_x + rhs.GetX(), _y + rhs.GetY());
}
```

For some reason which is unknown to me It doesn't want to take "x" and "y" however I have this problem only with this program with calculations it works like a charm.

Thank you for help

Comment: You are drawing a line of length 0. Ignoring the fact, that you are using the wrong macro to [extract the position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown#remarks) in the `LineTo` call, they are just the same values you are passing to `MoveToEx`. Lines are endpoint-exclusive, resulting in a line of length 0.

Comment: @JonathanPotter MAKEPOINTS take only single argument based on VS and documentation

Comment: @llnspectable how to do it please? should i include MOUSEMOVE or BUTTONUP?

Comment: hi, what do you want to draw using connectLines?Do you want to draw a continuous line segment based on the click of the mouse?

Comment: @Dr.Noob yes, that is what you need. Use `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to save the starting point, and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` to save additional points while the left button is held down. Draw lines between the saved points in `WM_PAINT`

Comment: @JeffreyShao-MSFT Hello i Want to draw lines at first just line between first and last click. Afterward draw like in paint or similar simple drawing program. Problem is that it must be stored in ‘vector <Vertex> connectLines;’

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hello the problem is that I need to store points in ```vector<Vertex> connectLines;``` and I don't know how to correctly store it and call it

Comment: @Dr.Noob what I said still applies. It is just a matter of converting the mouse coordinates to `Vertex`elements, and you already know how to do that. The rest is just `WM_PAINT` looping through the `vector` drawing the lines. See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the line start and end at the same point. So you fail to draw line. 
if your Vertex class function like this:

```
void Vertex::SetX(const int x)
{
    _x = x;
}

void Vertex::SetY(const int y)
{
    _y = y;
}
```

Draw a continous lines segment based on the click the mouse, you can code like this:

```
static POINT ptPrevious = { 0,0 };
static bool flag = false;
Vertex temp;
...
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        POINTS clickPoint = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
        if (flag == false) {
            ptPrevious.x = clickPoint.x;
            ptPrevious.y = clickPoint.y;
            flag = true;
        }
        //store the point in connectLines
        temp.SetX(clickPoint.x);
        temp.SetY(clickPoint.y);
        connectLines.push_back(temp);

        MoveToEx(hdc, ptPrevious.x, ptPrevious.y, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));

        //record previous point
        ptPrevious.x = clickPoint.x;
        ptPrevious.y = clickPoint.y;

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        break;
```

If you need to save the location of the mouse click, you need to add it yourself.
And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-with-the-mouse) provides a sample Drawing with the Mouse, but the variables should be `static` variable.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This approach is correct but I need to store points and use class Vertex. ```vector<Vertex> connectLines;``` I managed to create drawing program using ''ptPrevious.....'' but I really need to convert to program using mentioned classes.

Comment: You can change the start point of line by yourself. My code will not store the start point, if you need, just move `POINTS clickPoint = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);` and  `Vertex temp;
        temp.x = clickPoint.x;
        temp.y = clickPoint.y;
        connectLines.push_back(temp);` to the front of `MoveToEx()`

Comment: @JeffreShao-MSFT I tested your solution but it doesn't compile because based on VS there is no 'x' and 'y' in vertex so temp.x or temp.y can not be used. This is my Vertex class

Comment: @JeffreShao-MSFT `#pragma once
class Vertex
{
public:
 Vertex();
 Vertex(int x, int y);
 Vertex(const Vertex& other);

 // Accessors
 int GetX() const;
 void SetX(const int x);
 int GetY() const;
 void SetY(const int y);

 // Assigment operator
 Vertex& operator= (const Vertex& rhs);

 bool operator== (const Vertex& rhs) const;

 const Vertex operator+ (const Vertex& rhs) const;

private:
 int _x;
 int _y;
};

 `
sorry for formating. Idk why it is shown like this.

Comment: @JeffreShao-MSFT thank you for your code this one seems to work just fine but even if I put `temp.x ...` in front of `MoveToEx()` it always starts from {0,0} and not from the point of first mouse click. Is there any way how to make it work, please?

Comment: btw small edit is needed to make it work in vs 2019 as `HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd)` otherwise it throw an error.

Comment: You are right. I am still learning. So far I did only programs with data and just started to use graphical and win32. So it is kind of confusing for me. I was struggling with this program for some time. No matter what I did I just couldn't make it work with classes. Interesting I really like the way how you sorted out. :) thank you very much! thanks to you I can finally have peace in mind and move forward :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
vector<Vertex> connectLines;

void addClickPoint(HWND hWnd, int X, int Y)
{
    connectLines.push_back(Vertex(X, Y));
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
}

...

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    POINTS clickPoint = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
    addClickPoint(hWnd, clickPoint.x, clickPoint.y);

    /* alternatively:
    addClickPoint(hWnd, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
    */
}
break;

// optionally:
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    if (wParam & MK_LBUTTON)
    {
        POINTS clickPoint = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
        addClickPoint(hWnd, clickPoint.x, clickPoint.y);

        /* alternatively:
        addClickPoint(hWnd, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
        */
    }
}
break;
//

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    ...

    if (connectLines.size() > 1)
    {
        MoveToEx(hdc, connectLines[0].GetX(), connectLines[0].GetY(), NULL);
        for(size_t i = 1; i < connectLines.size(); ++i)
            LineTo(hdc, connectLines[i].GetX(), connectLines[i].GetY());
    }

    ...

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. 
It gives me an error: class Vertex has no member "x" please have a look on my Vertex class(it should be correct) because every time I tried to write this program I ended up with a similar problem